# Parallel ODE solver using deSolve in R?

Tags: r, foreach, ode, doparallel, desolve

I am trying to find the numerical solution for an ODE at time points (t_1,...,t_n) with parameters (theta_1,...,theta_n), where n is in the order of tens of thousands. In fact, this can be seen as n "independent" ODEs. Then, I need to repeat this M times, where M in the order of tens of thousands. That is, one ODE for each time point with different parameters, and only the first n steps are parallelizable.

Is there an efficient way of doing this? Should I parallelize it as a function of t's and theta's? I am currently using a for loop, but the equation I am interested in is slightly more complicated than the example below and n is in the order of tens of thousands. Thus, I would like to make an efficient implementation of this solver. I have also tried a naive parallel implementation of `foreach`, but the resulting code is even slower.

A reproducible example below, for M = 1, using the logistic ODE (I know this one has an analytic solution, just trying to present a reproducible toy example)

```
library(deSolve)

# Logistic ODE
logisode <- function(t, y, par) {
  # state variables  
  N <- y[1]

  # parameters
  lambda <- par[1]
  kappa <- par[2]
  
  # model equations
  dN <-  lambda*N*(1 - N/kappa) 

  # result  
  return( list(dN) )
  
}


lambdas = seq(0.1,1,by=0.1)
kappas = seq(0.1,1,by=0.1) + 1
ttimes <- seq(0.1, 25, length.out = 10)

out <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = length(lambdas))

for(i in 1:length(lambdas)){
params  <- c(lambda = lambdas[i], kappa = kappas[i], h0 = 0.1)
init      <- c(N = params[3])
times  <- c(0,ttimes[i]) 
out[i,] <- ode(init, times, logisode, params, method = "lsode")[-1,]
}

plot(out, type = "l")
```

Comment: Short question, which OS do you use? Windows or Linux?

Comment: @tpetzoldt I use macOS.

Comment: I don't have a MacOS at hand, but can add a Linux solution to my answer. This should in theory also work on Macs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example for Windows with `parApply`. The difficulty with Windows is, that the complete data have to be passed to each core. That's why packages and "shared" data need to be defined or loaded within `runModel`. This is easier for Linux, with `mcapply`, where the cores have access to global variables.

```r
library(parallel)

runModel <- function(params) {
  library(deSolve)
  logisode <- function(t, y, par) {
    N <- y[1]
    lambda <- par[1]
    kappa  <- par[2]
    dN     <-  lambda * N * (1 - N/kappa) 
    return( list(dN) )
  }

  init  <- c(N = params[3])
  times <- c(0, params[4]) 
  ret   <- ode(init, times, logisode, params, method = "lsode")[-1,]
  unname(ret) # discard names
}


lambdas <- seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1)
kappas  <- seq(0.1, 1, by =0.1) + 1
ttimes  <- seq(0.1, 25, length.out = 10)

params <- cbind(lambda = lambdas, kappa = kappas, h0 = 0.1, times=ttimes)

## single core version
#out <- apply(params, MARGIN = 1, FUN = runModel)

## parallel on 8 cores
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 8))
out <- parApply(cl, params, MARGIN = 1, FUN = runModel)
stopCluster(cl)

out <- t(out) # transpose matrix
plot(out, type = "l")
```

There are of also other possibilities, e.g. the  **future** package.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Very useful. I use macOS, are there any differences I should be aware of?

Comment: MacOS is essentially a UNIX system, so `mclapply` should also work.

Comment: May I ask another question? As I know you are one of the developers of `deSolve`.

What do you think about `diffeqr` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diffeqr/vignettes/gpu.html) compared to this kind of parallelization? Does it have potential to be much faster?

I am considering this alternative, but the learning curve looks steep.

Comment: Yes `diffeqr` from Chris Rackauckas is an excellent package. I have not tried the GPU accelerated version yet, but it sounds very promising.